# ES lint requires redux state as useEffect dependency which would cause infinite re-renders

Tags: reactjs, redux, use-effect

I have a component in which I m using `useSelector` to get the state from redux which is an object. One of the properties of the redux state contains a key with a previous value. When component mounts, in `useEffect` I need to make a network request with redux state having that property updated which had a previous value, but I only need to do it once.

After that network request is done I dispatch an action to update the state on frontend so that both states, stored on backend and frontend are synchronized. ES lint complains that I should pass the state as a dependency, but if I do that it will enter in an infinite re-render. What is the right way of fixing this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `// eslint-disable-next-line` to a line before the dependencies...

Comment: So I guess there is no workaround this right? It s the only way to fix in this case since it is about redux state.